# How do I make sure a callback is only added once?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have some code like this..

```
.factory('Auth', function($firebaseAuth) {
var ref = new Firebase('https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com');
return $firebaseAuth(ref);
})
```

and a controller

```
.controller("LoginCtrl", function($scope, Auth, $timeout) {
function authDataCallback(authData) {
    $timeout(function() {
        console.log(Auth);
        $scope.user = authData;

        if (authData) {    
            console.log("Authentication ok.");
        }
    });
}

$scope.auth = Auth;
console.log("Adding a new callback in login");
$scope.auth.$onAuth(authDataCallback);
...
```

In my app, the visitor may be redirected back to the login page (and this LoginCtrl controller gets called again). What happens is that the same callback gets added again. So on returning to the login page a few times, the code in the callback gets called multiple times.

How do I cancel/delete the callbacks on leaving/loading a controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a public boolean property to your Auth service which holds the authentication state of the user. once user is authenticated set it to true.

Then before you call the callback check if based on that previous value setting it is needed to run the callback code or not.

```
if (!Auth.isUserAuthenticated) {
   $scope.auth.$onAuth(authDataCallback);
}
```

I have to say, I could show you patterns of forcing a function to run only once either from lodash or elsewhere, but what is the real issue is that controllers unlike services etc. are not singletons and expressions run at least once during the digest cycle and the digest cycle is not a one time only process. Your problem is architectural as your controller holds logic that is more than just managing behavior.

You need to ensure that all of the main business logic of your app is inside services and controllers only manage their own behavior by either calling methods on those services or reading a state from them.

This is a sketch but I hope you get the general principle.

Comment: Right I get the idea. It's not just for when they are authenticated though. It's more for if they have visited that page before.. to know whether to add the callback to detect a change in auth. So I'll also need to add another boolean for every other page that I add this callback to keep track. e.g. the page with the logout button.

Comment: What are these auth changes from one page to another? What are you exactly trying to track?

Comment: On another page/view (profile.html) there is a logout button with ng-click="auth.$unauth()" which then fires the $onAuth() callback detailed in the controller for that view. If I load that profile.html page (either through refresh or navigating back to it) more than once, the callback in that controller gets called/executed multiple times.

Comment: So for my question, your solution definitely works! So thanks! I think a better design might be to have the callback added for a controller attached to a navbar. I.e. it just gets loaded once, instead of a controller being loaded again for each time its view gets loaded.